# Angular preload strategy did not load Forms/ReactiveForms Module?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

while trying to create an app using ionic boilerplate, I keep encounter error such as:

> no provider for NgControl

> 'form group' is not a known property of 'form'

searching for both error above only return me result of "import **FormsModule** and **ReactiveFormsModule** in *app.module*" which I already did but not working

I then spend half a day, randomly rearrange codes to no avail until finally I remove the

```
{ preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }
```

code which generated from boilerplate under *app-router.module* and my apps finally works

sample:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: gdUserLoginComponent },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
```

can someone help explain what is actually going on and whether what I did is the correct solution?

I also want to add another behavior regarding my issue is that:
If I set the login.component as the first route when the app load, all the forms related items(formGroup, formcontrolname, validator, etc) function properly. But whenever I left the component and then use the angular router to navigate back into login.component, I'll start getting error as mentioned above

Comment: It's **not**:"import FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in app.module" else "import FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in the module where you're declared the component" (if your component is declared in,e.g. component.module.ts, is in this module where you need import ReactiveFormsModule

Comment: @Eliseo I've declared the login component and imported FormsModule/ReactiveFormsModule all in app.module for simplicity but still receive the same error.  

To add to that: when I tried to have login.component be the 1st page whenever the app is loaded, everything works fine including the form. But when I use the router to navigate to login.component, only then will I receive the error